# How to use Q objects in Django

Tags: python, django, search

I am trying to understand how to make a simple search form for a website in Django. After some google search and few failures to do it on my own I ended up with the following code in views.py where 'q' is value retrieved from the form:

```
class BookSearchListView(BookListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        result=super(BookSearchListView, self).get_queryset()
        query=self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            query_list=query.split()
            result=result.filter(reduce(operator.and_,(Q(title__icontains=q) for q in query_list))) 
        return result
```

I already understand how it works and why there is reduce and operator.and_ (I mean, I think I understand). But I do not understand why a simple  `result=result.filter(Q(somedbfield_icontains=q))` returns and error (even if input is a single word). I also don't understand why reduce needs to get bitwise value?

Comment: Can you add the exact error messages that you're getting?

Comment: when I reduce it to result=result.filter(Q(title__icontains=q) for q in query_list)  exception I get is: "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: You can't pass an iterable to filter

Comment: `reduce(operator.and_, (a, b, c, ...))` is the same as `a and b and c and ...`

Comment: So this is there is and_ : to get single non-iterable value ? If yes then what is the purpose of reduce()?

Comment: Ok , after Igonato's update I understand it. Reduce is used so and_ can effectively join iterable elements (terms passed by user) into non-iterable. Thanks a lot it is much clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why a simple result.filter(Q(somedbfield_icontains=q)) returns and error

The simplest variant would be `result.filter(somedbfield__icontains=q)` Q isn't needed there, Q is used to extend your filtering with logic operators (and, or, not). Also, notice the double underscore before `icontains`.

> why reduce needs to get bitwise value?

[It dosen't](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce)

`reduce` is used to apply any function to an iterable of arguments:

`operator.add(1, 2)` is the same as `1 + 2`

`reduce(operator.add, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))` is the same as `((((1 + 2) + 3) + 4) + 5)`

Works roughly like this:

```
def reduce(function, iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    value = next(it)

    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)

    return value
```

Comment: Thanks. So Q is used here because there might be multiple terms in the input so it needs to use OR ? Is that right?

Comment: Exactly. Q can be used with logic operators (and, or, not)